# Перегрузка оператора сравнения

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <Windows.h>
..............
struct info
{
    int art;
    char item[N];
};
struct shop
{
    info x;
    int price;
    char proiz[N];
    char madein[N];
};
..............
int operator>(shop v,shop w)
{
    if (strcmp (v.madein,w.madein)>0) return 1;
    if (strcmp (v.madein,w.madein)<0) return 0;
    if (strcmp (v.proiz,w.proiz)>0) return 1;
    if (strcmp (v.proiz,w.proiz)<0) return 0;
    if (strcmp(v.x.item,w.x.item)>0) return 1;
    if (strcmp(v.x.item,w.x.item)<0) return 0;
    else return 0;
}
...........
void list1::sortmadein()
    {
        int fl;
        node1 *p0,*p1,*p2;
        if(beg1==NULL || beg1->next==NULL) return;
        do {fl=0;
             p1=beg1; p2=beg1->next;
            if (p1->d.madein>p2->d.madein)
               {p1->next=p2->next;
                p2->next=p1;
                beg1=p2;
                fl=1;

            }
            for(p0=beg1;p0->next->next !=NULL; p0=p0->next)
            {p1=p0->next; p2=p1->next;
            if (p1->d.madein>p2->d.madein)
            {p1->next=p2->next;
            p2->next=p1;
            p0->next=p2;
            fl=1;}
            }
        } while (fl==1);
        printscreen();
}
```

Есть 2 структуры, они перед вами.
1 перегруженный оператор сравнения.
И моя сортировка.

Проблема такая: сортировка не работает в представленном состоянии, но начинает работать когда условия проверки делаю таким: if (p1->d>p2->d) все божественным образом работает.</br>
**Возникает первый вопрос, а почему?! ведь не понятно что сравнивать.**</br>
Таких сортировок у меня 5(по штуке на каждое поле), 2 числовых с ними все просто, 3 строковых. При работе программы создается ощущение, что в код перегрузки только первые 2 строчки поля madein воспринимаются программой, остальные нет. Переместив вверх 2 условия поля proiz чудесным образом сортируется только это поле.

### Пример:

<code>
int operator>(shop v,shop w)
    {
        if (strcmp (v.proiz,w.proiz)>0) return 1;
        if (strcmp (v.proiz,w.proiz)<0) return 0;
        if (strcmp (v.madein,w.madein)>0) return 1;
        if (strcmp (v.madein,w.madein)<0) return 0;
        if (strcmp(v.x.item,w.x.item)>0) return 1;
        if (strcmp(v.x.item,w.x.item)<0) return 0;
        else return 0;
    }
</code>
**Что не так, мои умные посетители данного ресурса?**

Comment: Вы бы описание типа `node1` тоже привели.

В `p1->d.madein` *madein* это что -- shop?

Comment: Вот узел
struct node1
{shop d;node1 *next;};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int operator>(shop v,shop w)
{
    if (strcmp (v.madein,w.madein)>0) return 1;
    if (strcmp (v.madein,w.madein)<0) return 0;

    if (strcmp (v.proiz,w.proiz)>0) return 1;
    if (strcmp (v.proiz,w.proiz)<0) return 0;

    if (strcmp(v.x.item,w.x.item)>0) return 1;
    if (strcmp(v.x.item,w.x.item)<0) return 0;
    else return 0;
}
```

**какое-то странное сравнение...**

[strcmp() описание](http://lord-n.narod.ru/download/books/walla/programming/Spr_po_C/14/strcmp.htm) читаем и думаем что же вам надо на самом деле.

если же  вам действительно надо "так сравнивать" то

```
int operator>(shop v,shop w)
{
    if (strcmp (v.madein,w.madein)>0 ||
        strcmp (v.proiz,w.proiz)>0 ||
        strcmp(v.x.item,w.x.item)>0 
    ) return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

---

---

---

**upd**

[[@adrug](/users/4514/adrug)](/users/4514/adrug) конкретно в С++ более красиво\лаконично\целесообразно\безошибочно\надёжно и т.д. использовать

1. class вместо struct (гуглим
       разницу...)
2. использовать класс  [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)
       вместо char* (гуглим разницу...)
3. вместо своего  ["велосипеда"](http://lurkmore.to/%c8%e7%ee%e1%f0%e5%f2%e0%f2%fc_%e2%e5%eb%ee%f1%e8%ef%e5%e4)
       **list1** использовать [std::list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) (гуглим разницу...)

советую сделать так: "реализовать своё творение, в стиле говнокода" (поднимаем скилл практики, и базу знаний по ошибкам), а затем реализовать "в стиле тру программиста" (поднимаем скилл теории и получаем огромный опыт). Ну а после почитать что-то типо [90 рекомендаций по стилю написания программ на C++](http://habrahabr.ru/post/172091/) и постичь мантру С++

p.s. так как ща идут недели зачётов то радует "правильно" поставленный вопрос от нового пользователя, а не как обычно :)

Comment: Мысль хорошая, но сортировка работать не стала.

Comment: Естественно, посколько это просто оптимизация Вашего `operator>`. Результат-то тот же.

Comment: как верно заметил avp это всёго лишь оптимизация, вообще непонятно что и как вы хотите сравнивать (и соответственно что и как сортировать), уж не говоря о смешении С и С++

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat, а вот я в своем комментарии тут ошибся. Ваша реализация сравнения не эквивалентна `operator>()` у ТС и вообще неправильная.

Смотрите, если `strcmp (v.madein,w.madein) == 0`, то надо сравнивать дальше, а у Вас сразу выйдет на `return 0;`

Правильная логика в ответе @VladD.

Comment: @avp да действительно вы правы, изменил "&&" на "||" теперь сравнение эквивалентно.

в такие моменты я жалею что в C++ нету оператора "&" и "|" из java

Comment: ан нет всё равно не эквивалентно... 

при strcmp (v.madein,w.madein) == -1

Answer (score 3):

Для начала, у вас ужасно неэффективно написан оператор сравнения. Непредусмотренное копирование (а у вас каждое сравнение копирует оба сравниваемых элемента) может приводить к проблемам.

Попробуйте так:

```
bool operator > (const shop& v, const shop& w)
{
    int madeInResult = strcmp (v.madein, w.madein);
    if (madeInResult != 0)
        return madeInResult > 0;

    int proizResult = strcmp (v.proiz, w.proiz);
    if (proizResult != 0)
        return proizResult > 0;

    int infoItemResult = strcmp(v.x.item, w.x.item);
    if (infoItemResult != 0)
        return infoItemResult;

    return 0;
}
```

Скорее всего, это не исправит все проблемы, так что пишите о результатах.

Совет на будущее: если вы уж пишете на C++, используйте не структуры, а классы, не `char[]`, а `std::string`, а сортируйте при помощи `std::sort`.

Comment: Проблема не решилась, спасибо за советы. Многие пишут, что мешаешь C и C++, но никто не указывает пальцем.
Причина того что у меня все в кашу, то что основные знания я получаю от нашего преподавателя. А у него своя программа обучения нас C++.

Comment: @adrug: А вы оттрассируйте код сами. Посмотрите, как ведёт себя сравнение. Мало ли что именно вы делаете не так. Может, у вас строки без финального `\0`.

Comment: Проблема оказалась гораздо проще, т.к. сравнение шло p1->d < p2->d, при проходе по оператору перегрузке он входил в первый IF и если условие удовлетворяло он сразу вываливался из него. Мысль пользователя @ProkletyiPirat была правильно, только я понял это не так скоро.

Comment: @adrug: Тогда вам стоит принять ответ, который помог вам решить проблему.